# Apple Push Notifications (APN) Connection Error (works locally)

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications

so I just got APN to work locally using the PushSharp library for C#. I can send it by clicking a button and see it on my phone.

The issue is when I deploy to the server, I get an error:

```
Failure: One or more errors occurred. -> {"aps":{"alert":"Test!","badge":1,"sound":"default","category":"none"}}
Apns notification error: 'ConnectionError'
```

There isn't a whole lot of information to go off of. So far, I have created a rule in Windows Firewall to allow outbound traffic on port 2195. I have also contacted my datacenter / provider and verified that the port is not blocked for outbound traffic.

I am having trouble finding specific information about this online, any advice / pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Which server provider you are using ? GoDaddy ?

Comment: Godaddy and some other providers doesn't open port 2195 on their shared hosting. That's why you may face this error.

Comment: Its in a private data center, where I have verified the port is open on the firewall and connected from that server, outbound, to APNS server 17.188.168.14 via port 2195 using telnet.

Comment: You only need port 2195 to be open for outbound connections. If you are getting notification on local server then there is something on your private server which is preventing port 2195 to be communicated with the APN server.

Comment: Does the fact that I can connect via command line / telnet not rule out firewall as the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue, which seems to be more of a bug with X509Certificate2 in .NET, but I figured I would document my fix here anyways because someone else may run into the same issue.

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\filepath.p12", "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

The third parameter is required on the server because by default, IIS is only allowed to get certificates out of the IIS user's key store. By passing the parameter X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet, it allows IIS to read and use certificates off of the filesystem.